# Unable to query SQL giving syntax error when converting DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm having a syntax error when making this SQL query from SQL Server Management Studio:

```
exec QData N'Name,Value,TimeStamp', 
     convert(datetime, '2013-11-25 03:25:02.000'), 
     N'IncludeBounding', N'Root.BDV101.Response.Value'
```

It says

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'

Anybody know why?

Edit:

If I do the following, it works (no error)

```
Declare @time datetime
Set @time = '2013-11-25 03:25:02.000'
exec QData N'Name, Value, TimeStamp', @time, N'IncludeBounding', N'Root.BDV101.Response.Value'
```

Comment: You cannot use functions and expression in the `EXEC` call - if you need to do some conversions etc., you have to do it **before** the call and store the results in variables (as in your second attempt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Implicit Conversion, like this:

```
exec QData N'Name,Value,TimeStamp','20131125 03:25:02.000',N'IncludeBounding',N'Root.BDV101.Response.Value'
```

Comment: It doesn't work as well.. no error comes but no data is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,without conversion it will take by default Datatime DAtatype

```
exec QData N'Name,Value,TimeStamp','2013-11-25 03:25:02.000' ,N'IncludeBounding',N'Root.BDV101.Response.Value'
```